# Count the subtree - optimise

Tags: python-3.x, tree, graph-theory, depth-first-search

**COUNT THE SUBTREES**

Given a tree having N nodes numbered from 1 to N and (N-1) edges where the ith edge is between node Edges [i][0] and node Edges[i][1].

The tree is rooted at node 1 and each node has a colour where the colour of the ith node is given by A[i].

Count the number of subtrees that do not contain any two nodes which have the same color.

Example:

```
Input:
N = 4
A[] = {1, 1, 2, 3}
Edges[][] = {{1, 2},
             {2, 3},
             {2, 4}}
Output:
3
Explanation: 
The structure of the tree is:
     1
     |
     2
    /  \ 
   3    4
There are only three subtrees rooted at node 2, 3 and 4 which do not contain any two 
nodes of the same color.
The subtree rooted at node 1 contains two nodes which have the same color 
(i.e. node 1 and node 2)

Input: 
N = 2
A[] = {5, 2} 
Edges[][] = {{2, 1}} 
Output: 
2
```

Constraints:

```
1 <= N <= 10^5
1 <= A[i] <= 10^9
1 <= Edges[i][0], Edges[i][1] <= N
```

Code:

```
def countSubtree(self, N, A, edges):
        adj = defaultdict(list)
        for i in edges:
            adj[i[0]].append(i[1])
            adj[i[1]].append(i[0])
        visited = [0 for i in range(N)]    
        
        subtrees = 0
        def dfs(node):
            sofar = True
            colors = set([A[node-1]])
            
            visited[node-1] = 1
            for i in adj[node]:
                if visited[i-1] == 1:
                    continue
                
                check,temp = dfs(i)
                sofar = sofar and check
                
                if colors&temp:
                    sofar = False
                colors = colors|temp
            
            nonlocal subtrees
            if sofar:
                subtrees+=1
                
            visited[node-1] = 0
            return [sofar,colors]
        
        dfs(1)
        return subtrees
```

**The above code resulted in TLE. Is there any better approach to do this? Or can it be optimised?**

Comment: Can you link to the code challenge?

Comment: For which input did you get a TLE? And in which language. If python, can you tag python?

Comment: https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/contest/code-battle

Comment: For which input did you get a TLE?

Comment: The test case has been hidden @trincot. You could reach the challenge through this https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/contest/code-battle link

Comment: Sorry, but that site is asking for an account. No go for me.